# Implementing Automatic Memoization (returns a closured function) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, memoization

I've read

http://www.sitepoint.com/implementing-memoization-in-javascript/

### Automatic Memoization

> In all of the previous examples, the functions were explicitly modified to add memoization. It is also possible to implement a memoization infrastructure without modifying the functions at all. This is useful because it allows the function logic to be implemented separately from the memoization logic. This is done by creating a utility function which takes a function as input and applies memoization to it. The following memoize() function takes a function, “func”, as input. memoize() returns a new function which wraps a caching mechanism around “func”. Note that this function does not handle object arguments. In order to handle objects, a loop is required which would inspect each argument individually and stringify as needed.

```
function memoize(func) {
  var memo = {};
  var slice = Array.prototype.slice;

  return function() {
    var args = slice.call(arguments);

    if (args in memo)
      return memo[args];
    else
      return (memo[args] = func.apply(this, args));

  }
}
```

using this, I did

```
var fib = function(n)
{
  if (n <= 1)
  {
    return 1; // as the Fib definition in Math
  }
  else
  {
    return fib(n - 2) + fib(n - 1); // as the Fib definition in Math
  }
};

log(memoize(fib)(43));
log(fib(43));
```

However, I confirmed there's no effect.

I also tried a npm library for the same purpose,

https://github.com/medikoo/memoize

and

```
var memoize = require('memoizee');

log(memoize(fib)(43));
log(fib(43));
```

The result, same.

What do I miss, and how to fix and make it work?

Thanks!

### EDIT

```
require('memoizee');

var fib = function(n)
{
  if (n <= 1)
  {
    return 1; // as the Fib definition in Math
  }
  else
  {
    return fib(n - 2) + fib(n - 1); // as the Fib definition in Math
  }
};

var generator = function(f)
{
  return memoize(f);
};

var _fib = generator(fib);
console.log(_fib(40)); //no effect
```

Comment: From what you posted only the first call uses the *memoize-d* function. The recursive calls all use the original `fib` function.

Comment: Oh sure.I see. Thinking how to fix. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `memoize` call does not alter the `fib` function, but returns its new, memoized counterpart. In your code, you're calling that one only once, and the original `fib` function the next time. You need to create *one* memoized "wrapper", and call that *multiple* times:

```
var mFib = memoize(fib);
log(mFib(43));
log(mFib(43));
```

You could also overwrite the original `fib = memoize(fib);`, which would have the additional benefit that the recursive calls (which are the interesting ones) will be memoized as well.

Comment: Cool. I like the over-writing idea. Usually, it's not recommended to do that in declarative, but my project is library for that. so I will employ. Great, thanks.

Comment: Since you usually need to manually apply memoisation to specific functions only, you could also just do it in their declaration: `var fib = memoize(function(n) { … fib(n-1) + fib(n-2) … });`

Comment: Thanks. On second thought, in my project, a generator function actually takes care of the function, in this case, `fib`, and does the rest of process. So, I cannnot Hard-code to over-write the fib in the same scope. I would like to avoid to add memoize in their declaration point if possible. In this case, you have any idea?

Comment: I know `underscore` http://underscorejs.org/#memoize does as you suggested now, but I wonder if there's any way to conceal that in the generator function.

Comment: No, if you cannot access that scope then you cannot optimise the (recursive calls of the) function by memoisation. However, if you cannot alter that module, it doesn't seem to be your cup of tea. Ask the developer that is responsible for it.

Comment: Thanks, this same scope issue gives me importance insight for my implementation.