# Higher Order Internal Memoization In JavaScript does not Work

Tags: javascript, memoization, higher-order-functions

**Context.**

Memoization is a functional technique operating over recursive functions with overlapping invocations aiming to optimize time performance by using an internal cache that remembers previous results with already used parameters. A typical use case is the fibonacci function. Below, it is shown  a non memoized and memoized version of that function and an assisting function for timing purposes:

```
function time (fn) {
   return function () {
      var before = Date.now();
      var result = fn.apply(this, arguments);
      var after  = Date.now();
      return {
         value : result,
         time  : after - before
      };
   };
}
var fib = function (n) {
   if (n < 2) return n;
   else return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
};
var mfib = function (n) {
   var cache = {};
   var memoizefib = function (n) {
      if (n < 2) return n;
      else {
         var k1 = JSON.stringify(n-1);
         var k2 = JSON.stringify(n-2);
         var v1 = k1 in cache ? cache[k1] : (cache[k1] = memoizefib(n-1));
         var v2 = k2 in cache ? cache[k2] : (cache[k2] = memoizefib(n-2));
         return v1 + v2;   
      }
   };
   return memoizefib (n);
};
```

If now we test our functions we realize that memoization dramatically reduces execution time:

```
(function test (n) {
   var tfib  = time(fib);
   var tmfib = time(mfib);
   console.log(tfib(n));  // -> { value: 433494437, time: 5780 }
   console.log(tmfib(n)); // -> { value: 433494437, time: 1 }    
})(43);
```

**Problem.**

As it frequently happens in functional programming, memoization becomes a useful tool when applied at the higher order to allow defining a `memoize` function that can transform over a generic function `fn`.  Typical solutions similar to the next one can be found on the Web [1][2][3]:

```
function memoize (fn) {
   var cache = {};
   return function () {
      var args  = [].slice.call (arguments); 
      var key   = JSON.stringify(args);
      return key in cache ?
         cache[key] :
         cache[key] = fn.apply(this, args); (1)
   };
}
```

1. fn.js - http://eliperelman.com/fn.js
2. underscore - http://underscorejs.org
3. Addy Osmani on Memoization - http://addyosmani.com/blog/faster-javascript-memoization

**Question.**

Nevertheless, surprisingly none of these solutions works!!! After revolving around the code. I think that the problem is in (1) because the recursion it is not applied over the memoized version of `fn` but over primitive `fn` and hence memoization is only applied once. Here are my results:

```
(function test (n) {
   var tfib  = time(fib);
   var tmfib = time(memoize(fib));
   console.log (tfib(n));  // -> { value: 433494437, time: 5768 }
   console.log (tmfib(n)); // -> { value: 433494437, time: 5723 } :(   
})(43);
```

It seems that in Javascript it is not possible to apply this technique at higher order. Am I right? Does anybody have any solution or alternative code to get a higher order memoization function?

Comment: Minor point, but there is no need to convert arguments to an array before stringifying it, JSON.stringify can handle arguments directly.

Comment: Note `in` operator also searches in the prototype, which could be bad is another script polluted `Object.prototype`. Using `cache.hasOwnProperty(key)` would be safer.

Comment: The problem lies in the recursive call, in mfib you call memoizefib(n-1)), in memoize, you simply call the real method again, so it doesn't do any cache checking.. I tried finding a solution to intercept the recursive call but i failed and i think it's not possible at all :)

Comment: Thanks Captain Obvious. As I said in my post,  what you are explaining is indeed the problem. What I was really questioning is if there are some kind of interception technique to apply the memoized version at the recursion call. So, what I keep in my mind is your last sentence confirming the impossibility.

Comment: You don't need to "intercept" the recursive call to apply the memoized version; you simply need to redefine the function being called recursively to be its memoized version. If the function in question is called "foo", and calls "foo" recursively, then if you redefine `foo = memoize(foo)", the recursive calls will now be made to the memoized version.

Comment: Oh my God! So that 'interception technique' that Captain Obvious refers in his comment is indeed a simple a redefinition trick. I now understand that this overwriting is what you meant by 'memoize the function onto itself'. I will try to seal that on my mind. Thanks a lot for your patient help torazaburo.

Comment: Yes. You will somehow need to make the recursive calls use the memoised function. Depending on the definition of the function, that might not be possible at all - you cannot/shouldnot simply change the behaviour of a function from outside. If a function is already defined, you might not be able to optimise it; that should be done in the declaration itself ([example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22578970/1048572)). You *always* can memoise though if *you* are doing multiple calls yourself (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24489141/1048572)).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Interesting problem. Why not just memoize the function onto itself?

```
function factorial(n) { return n ? n * factorial(n-1) : 1; }

// simple memoization with one argument and console reporting
function memoize(fn) {
    var cache = {};
    return function(x) {
        if (x in cache) { console.log('retrieved value from cache for', x); }
        return x in cache ? cache[x] : cache[x] = fn.apply(this, arguments);
    };
}

// redefine factorial to be its memoized version
factorial = memoize(factorial);
```

Once you do this, `factorial` will now be calling its memoized version.

```
> factorial(6)
720
> factorial(7)
retrieved value from cache for 6
5040
```

Applying this to your case (no need for `mfib`):

```
(function test (n) {
   var tfib  = time(fib);
   console.log(tfib(n));
   fib = memoize(fib);         // <-- memoize on top of itself
   var tmfib = time(fib);
   console.log(tmfib(n));
})(30);
```

Results:

```
Object {value: 832040, time: 714} 
Object {value: 832040, time: 22}
```

Note that this solution very much applies to "internal memoization" used within a single recursive computation, not just additional external calls to the function as in the factorial case above. By redefining the function with its memoized version, the internal recursive calls are now made to the memoized function. That accounts for the dramatic time improvement from 714 to 22.

Comment: Thanks torazaburo. Your solution is similar to the last one in Addy's blog. But this kind of approaches are only appropiate when you attempt to make external memoizing among successive invocations as you show in your example memoizing `factorial(7)` after invoking `factorial(6)`. Your solution does not apply internal memoization, which in the factorial function does not make sense but it does on overlapping recursion such as in the fibonacci case. External memoization is not confined to recursive schemes. Internal is used to solve recursive functions with overlapping calls

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I do not agree. It exactly optimizes the internal calls by using the memoized internal results. See edit to my answer.

Comment: I cannot see the connection with Addy's blog. What I am proposing is to sort of overwrite the function itself with its memoized version, so recursive calls it makes to itself are to the memoized version. I do not see where Addy talks about that, or indeed about recursion at all except in general terms.

Comment: Your example works properly, but I think you are mistaking a simple cacheing technique which can be applied both to recursive and not recursive functions with (internal) memoization which only make sense in recursive scenarios with overlapping invocations (multiple recursions). I suggest you to think about the problem with this kind of functions like the classical fibonacci.

Comment: With all due respect, I cannot parse what you are saying. Memoization **is** precisely caching, so it would be difficult for me to mistake one for the other. Memoization is memoization, whether its for a non-recursive function, or used in a recursive function "rewritten" as I am doing to use a memoized version of itself for the multiply recursive chain of calls. I showed an example of the time for a stand-alone Fibonacci calculation being reduced from 714 to 22, using a generic memoizer, with no previous memoized results. At a loss to understand what else you would be trying to achieve here.

Comment: In your comment above I realize, and now understand, your proposal. Your solution is perfect for me. Nevertheless, from your words I would summarize the following lesson learned: In JavaScript it is not possible to create a memoize function from a general one fn if you do not make use of the overwriting technique you are proposing. This implies that the previous version - the not memoized one - is lost. Nevertheless, thanks a lot for your contributions.

Comment: Unless I am terribly mistaken, I think this is wrong. `memoize` closes over the value of `fn` that is passed as an argument (functions are values, right?). Changing the variable `factorial` to point at the memoized version of the function does nothing. Also, factorial can't be used to demonstrate "internal memoization within a single computation", see my answer for more.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for "internal" memoization *within a single recursive computation*, the factorial function (which is given in the currently accepted answer - which BTW I also think is wrong) is a bad candidate and can't be used to showcase it. This is because, there's a single chain of recursion, so once you compute, e.g. the value for `5!` you are not going to need it again *within the same computation*. To showcase what you are asking for, you would indeed need to use an example like the Fibonnaci sequence (which you are yourself using in the question).

The higher-order `memoize` function you wrote will not work internally within the same computation as it is calling the non-memoized version of it. The currently accepted answer suggests "redefining" the function to be its memoized version. However I think this is wrong. The `memoize` function closes over the function it was provided with as an argument (functions are values). Changing the variable that used to point to that function value to some other function value (the `memoized` version) accomplishes nothing.

So, I don't think it is possible to generalize it. That is, I don't believe it is possible to implement a `memoize` function that externally memoizes a function and makes it work also for a single recursive computation.

Here's what **would** work for Fibonnaci (like I said, not generalizable):

```
    var fib = (function() {

        function fib(n) {
            if ((n===1) || (n==2))
                return 1;
            else
                return memoizedFibonacci(n-1)+memoizedFibonacci(n-2);
        }

        var cache = {};

        function memoizedFibonacci(n) {
            if (n in cache) { console.log('retrieved value from cache for', n); }
            return n in cache ? cache[n] : cache[n] = fib(n);
        };

        return fib;
    })();

    console.log(fib(10));
    console.log(fib(10));
```

The above code produces on the output:

```
retrieved value from cache for 2
retrieved value from cache for 3
retrieved value from cache for 4
retrieved value from cache for 5
retrieved value from cache for 6
retrieved value from cache for 7
retrieved value from cache for 8
55
retrieved value from cache for 9
retrieved value from cache for 8
55
```

... which is consistent with the expectation for "internal memoization" for the first recursive computation. That the value for 10 is not cached is insignificant for this example and could be trivially fixed but it would add very little (basically you would need to access the cache from the `fib` function as well).